# Create a new unique 12 digit number php

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table of bar-codes in MySQL database where bar code numbers are stored and we are creating new bar-code number but problem is that how to generate a new 12 digit number which should not be duplicate by our database table.We have already created the function to check duplicate Number.

```
  <?php include('dbcon.php');

 function IsBarcodeDuplicate($bcodeno){
 $sqlsearch="SELECT * FROM barcodes where barcodeno='$barcodeno'";
 $rs=mysqli_query($_GLOBALS['con'],$sqlsearch);
 $rowcounts=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
 if($rowcounts>=1){
 return(true);  
 }
return(false);
}//ends here

function GenerateNewnum(){
/*to be implemented here
IsBarcodeDuplicate(number) 
*/
 }//ends here
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just increment the highest number in your db table by 1? Then you wouldn't need to check if it already exists.

```
SELECT barcodeno FROM barcodes ORDER BY barcodeno DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or you could just use php's random number generator and pad 0's in front if it is shorter than 12 characters.

```
$no = rand(0, 999999999999);
$no = str_pad($no, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: My bar code reader is also scanning other products which already have bar codes and then inserting in the table but the problem arises when we have to create a new number for a produc which has no barcode  and inserting it to table without duplication @George

Comment: Hi Syed, I understand that, and by selecting the highest value and incrementing it by one, you are guaranteed a unique number (as it is higher than any other number in the table).